# MacOS no longer supports mpi compiler on GitHub actions?

Tags: macos, github-actions, mpi

I am working on a project which is a science software package: https://github.com/NOAA-EMC/NCEPLIBS-ncio

We have a GitHub actions workflow for the MacOS which uses MPI parallel programming. It worked until about a week ago, and then it stopped. Here's what I've got:

```
# This is a GitHub CI workflow for the NCEPLIBS-ncio project.
#
# This workflow runs the build on MacOS.
#
# Ed Hartnett 1/12/23
name: MacOS
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - develop
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - develop

jobs:
  MacOS:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    env:
      FC: mpifort
      CC: mpicc
      HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP: 1

    steps:

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: install-dependencies
      run: |
        brew update
        brew install --verbose sbtn mpich
        sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/gfortran-11 /usr/local/bin/gfortran

    - name: cache-netcdf
      id: cache-netcdf
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: ~/netcdf
        key: netcdf-c-4.7.4-${{ runner.os }}1

    - name: build-hdf5
      if: steps.cache-netcdf.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      run: |
        wget https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.10/hdf5-1.10.7/src/hdf5-1.10.7.tar.gz &> /dev/null
        tar -xzf hdf5-1.10.7.tar.gz
        pushd hdf5-1.10.7
        ./configure --prefix=${HOME}/netcdf --enable-parallel --disable-tools --disable-fortran --disable-cxx --enable-parallel-tests
        make -j2
        make install
```

This fails because the HDF5 build cannot find mpicc. Where does brew install mpich actually put mpicc? I can't find it anywhere...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think brew install it's stuff in /opt on M1. Try running find /usr/local/Cellar to double check what was installed.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet At this time, macOS runners in GitHub Actions are only Intel

Comment: @EdwardHartnett macos-latest runners have just been migrated to macOS 12. Try to pin your workflow back to a macOS 11 runner and see if that is the cause of the issue. Change `runs-on: macos-latest` to `runs-on: macos-11`

Comment: But otherwise Gilles is correct: `/usr/local/Cellar/mpich/3.3.2`